# Where do you put the suffix when listing the last name first?

Tags: names, suffixes

When listing names with the last name first, where should you put the suffix if there is one present? For example, if given the name `John Doe Jr.`, which of the following would be correct?

- `Doe, John Jr.`
- `Doe, John, Jr.`   *<- My guess is this one*
- `Doe Jr., John`
- `Jr., Doe, John`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that the correct answer to this is *refer to your style guide*, e.g., [APA](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/03/jr-sr-and-other-suffixes-in-apa-style.html), [MLA](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/05/), [IEEE](http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecitationref.pdf), [SPIE](http://spie.org/x85020.xml), etc. These should fully specify details like this, and you only sometimes get lucky and have a real human address specific concerns like this (viz., the APA link).

In contrast to what @bib suggests, the [APA reference](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/03/jr-sr-and-other-suffixes-in-apa-style.html) requires that you include a comma between the first name and the suffix:

> Doe, John, Jr.

(Also please note that the gentleman's official name will have a comma in it: `John Doe, Junior` or `John Doe, Jr.`.)

Comment: I accepted your answer over @bib's because you gave references to official sources.

Answer (score 8):

The suffix is an explanation of the first name, not the last. "John Doe Jr." means he is John, the son of John. In a full name listing, the suffix follows the last name because the person is primarily known by is given name and surname, the suffix being a secondary piece of information.

When listing last name first, the given name follows the surname because that is how we sort: all the Does, then the Johns, and finally the Jr.s.

The preferred form would be

> Doe, John Jr.

Comment: But, if this is for bibliographical software, RTFM to see what the software expects.

Answer (score 0):

Use a comma before Jr. and Sr., but treat II and III according to the person’s
preference. Within a sentence, always use a comma after Jr. and Sr., but use a
comma after II and III only if they are preceded by a comma.

William M. Delaney, Jr.

Charles J. Smith, III

John J. Alden II

William M. Delaney, Jr., was elected to the governing board.

Charles J. Smith, III, received a majority of the votes.

John J. Alden II did not run for office this year.

--*The ACS Style Guide*; American Chemical Society: Washington, DC, USA, 2006; p. 117.

Comment: That does not answer the question: "... when listing the last name first"!

Answer (score -7):

The suffix will always be at the end (the meaning of *suffix*).