# Where do you put a prefix and suffix when listing last names first?

Tags: names

I'm listing names last name first, but it is important to have all name parts included. Let's say I had a `Dr. Leonard B. McCoy Jr.`. Should I list him as `McCoy, Dr. Leonard B. Jr.`? I read [another question about suffixes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116856/where-do-you-put-the-suffix-when-listing-the-last-name-first), but couldn't find anything about prefixes. If the suffix goes at the end, does it go before or after the suffix, and are there commas?

Comment: @Laurel It helps, but doesn't quite answer my full question. For prefix alone, it indicates I would do "McCoy, Leonard, Dr.", but then does "Jr." go before or after "Dr."?

Comment: The British courts system lists Mr Joseph Richard Bloggs QC in surname-first format as Bloggs, Mr Joseph Richard QC. No comma.